# How would I change the contents of a value in a string in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

If I have a string that looks like this, how would I change the first value to true and then in another call, turn the second value to true

```
echo "{\"item0\":\"$item0\", \"item1\":\"$item1\", \"item2\":\"$item2\", \"item3\":\"$item3\", \"item4\":\"$item4\", \"Success1\":false, \"Success2\":false, \"item4\":\"$item4\", \"item5\":\"$item5\"}" > curldata.txt
```

This is the output I want in the first case

```
echo "{\"item0\":\"$item0\", \"item1\":\"$item1\", \"item2\":\"$item2\", \"item3\":\"$item3\", \"item4\":\"$item4\", \"Success1\":true, \"Success2\":false, \"item4\":\"$item4\", \"item5\":\"$item5\"}" > curldata.txt
```

I have seen other methods that can change areas depending on the line, but I am unsure for a string that has lots of quotes and similarities in it

Comment: you are sending the `echo` output to a file; are you looking to edit the file afterwards? are you looking to (somehow) modify the `echo` command *before* writing to the file? how is this string being built in the first place (and why not just build it with the desired `true` entries)? is the string by any chance initially stored in a variable?

Comment: will the first 'value' always be `false`? will the 'value' entries always be associated with `Success1` and `Success2`? will there always be *just* 2 values to be modified? it's not clear (to me) if we're just replacing 2x `false` entries with 2x `true` entries or if we have also have to take into account field names/labels and/or a variable number of field/values ... ?

Comment: I'm pulling something and then pushing something. So after each command, I will update my file it if was successful. If it was not successful then it will end the script and save that in a file, which another script will access. Always just those two values will be modified and nothing else. And it will always start with false and be changed to true

Answer (score 1):

```
jq '.Success1 = true | .Success2 = true' curldata.txt | sponge curldata.txt
```

Adjust the true/false values accordingly.

`sponge` is found in the `moreutils` package.

Comment: This is all run in a gitlab pipeline. Is sponge accessible in gitlab?

Comment: `in a gitlab pipeline. Is sponge accessible in gitlab?` That depends on the gitlab-runner used... but if it's the default with docker executor, use a docker container where you can install stuff and install all dependencies that you require, like jq or sponge.